# The message tag is being sent to html document but it's not visible

Tags: python, html, css, django

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/signup.css" %}"  type="text/css"/>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% if messages %}
      <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <!-- FORM SECTION -->
      <div class="row">
        <!-- SIGN UP -->
        <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-up">
          <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center">
            <form class="form sign-up" id="signup-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="signup">
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
                <select name="role" class="form-control" required>
                  {% for value, label in form.role.field.choices %}
                      <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == '' %}disabled="disabled" selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bxs-user"></i>
                {{ form.username }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bx-mail-send"></i>
                {{ form.email }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bxs-lock-alt"></i>
                {{ form.password }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bxs-lock-alt"></i>
                {{ form.confirm_password }}
              </div>
              <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
              <p>
                <span> Already have an account? </span>
                <b onclick="toggle()" class="pointer"> Sign in here </b>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END SIGN UP -->
        <!-- SIGN IN -->
        <div class="col align-items-center flex-col sign-in">
          <div class="form-wrapper align-items-center">
            <form class="form sign-in" id="signin-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="signin">
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
                <select name="role" class="form-control" required>
                  {% for value, label in form.role.field.choices %}
                      <option value="{{ value }}" {% if value == '' %}disabled="disabled" selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bxs-user"></i>
                {{ form.username }}
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <i class="bx bxs-lock-alt"></i>
                {{ form.password }}
              </div>
              <button type="submit"><a href="/signin">Sign in</a></button>
              <p>
                <b> Forgot password? </b>
              </p>
              <p>
                <span> Don't have an account? </span>
                <b onclick="toggle()" class="pointer"> Sign up here </b>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="form-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- END SIGN IN -->
      </div>
      <!-- END FORM SECTION -->
      <!-- CONTENT SECTION -->
      <div class="row content-row">
        <!-- SIGN IN CONTENT -->
        <div class="col align-items-center flex-col">
          <div class="text sign-in">
            <h2>Welcome</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="img sign-in"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- END SIGN IN CONTENT -->
        <!-- SIGN UP CONTENT -->
        <div class="col align-items-center flex-col">
          <div class="img sign-up"></div>
          <div class="text sign-up">
            <h2>Join with us</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END SIGN UP CONTENT -->
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTENT SECTION -->
    </div>

    {% comment %} <ul class="messages">
      <li class="error">
        Hello
      </li>
    </ul> {% endcomment %}

    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#signup-form").submit(function (e) {
            // Prevent the default form submission (page refresh)
            e.preventDefault();
    
            var formData = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'signup' %}",
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle the response from the server
                    console.log(response); // For demonstration purposes, you can log the response to the console
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                },
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/signup.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

signup.css

```
:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(221, 60, 60);
    --secondary-color: rgba(221, 60, 60, 0.884);
    --black: #000000;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --gray: #efefef;
    --gray-2: #757575;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
}

.align-items-center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.form-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 28rem;
}

.form {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--white);
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.input-group i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 1rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: var(--gray-2);
}

.input-group input,
.input-group select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: var(--gray);
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--white);
    outline: none;
}

.input-group input:focus,
.input-group select:focus {
    border: 0.125rem solid var(--primary-color);
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.form button {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .6rem 0;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    outline: none;
}

.form p {
    margin: 1rem 0;
    font-size: .7rem;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container.sign-in .form.sign-in,
.container.sign-up .form.sign-up {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.content-row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 100%;
}

.text {
    margin: 4rem;
    color: var(--white);
}

.text h2 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.text p {
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}

.img img {
    width: 30vw;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

.text.sign-in h2,
.text.sign-in p,
.img.sign-in img {
    transform: translateX(-250%);
}

.text.sign-up h2,
.text.sign-up p,
.img.sign-up img {
    transform: translateX(250%);
}

.container.sign-in .text.sign-in h2,
.container.sign-in .text.sign-in p,
.container.sign-in .img.sign-in img,
.container.sign-up .text.sign-up h2,
.container.sign-up .text.sign-up p,
.container.sign-up .img.sign-up img {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

/* BACKGROUND */

.container::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300vw;
    transform: translate(35%, 0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--primary-color) 0%, var(--secondary-color) 100%);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 6;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: max(50vw, 50vh);
    border-top-left-radius: max(50vw, 50vh);
}

.container.sign-in::before {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    right: 50%;
}

.container.sign-up::before {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
    right: 50%;
}


/* message block */

/* Style the entire message block */
ul.messages {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 300ms ease;
}

/* Style individual message items based on their type */
ul.messages li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul.messages .success {
    background-color: #5cb85c; /* Green for success messages */
    color: #fff;
}

ul.messages .info {
    background-color: #5bc0de; /* Blue for info messages */
    color: #fff;
}

ul.messages .warning {
    background-color: #f0ad4e; /* Orange for warning messages */
    color: #fff;
}

ul.messages .error {
    background-color: #d9534f; /* Red for error messages */
    color: #fff;
}



/* RESPONSIVE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {

    .container::before,
    .container.sign-in::before,
    .container.sign-up::before {
        height: 100vh;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        transform: none;
        right: 0;
    }

    .container.sign-in .col.sign-up {
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .container.sign-in .col.sign-in,
    .container.sign-up .col.sign-up {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    .content-row {
        align-items: flex-start !important;
    }

    .content-row .col {
        transform: translateY(0);
        background-color: unset;
    }

    .col {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: var(--white);
        border-top-left-radius: 2rem;
        border-top-right-radius: 2rem;
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .row {
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .form {
        box-shadow: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .text {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .text p {
        display: none;
    }

    .text h2 {
        margin: .5rem;
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import LoginForm, SignupForm
from .models import CustomUser


def home(request):
    login_form = LoginForm()
    signup_form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup/index.html', {'form': login_form, 'form': signup_form})



def signup(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            role = form.cleaned_data['role']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            confirm_password = form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
            
            existing_user = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).first()
            
            if existing_user is not None:
                if existing_user.username == username:
                    messages.info(request, 'Username already exists')
                elif existing_user.role == role:
                    messages.error(request, 'User with the same email and role already exists')
                else:
                    myuser = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                    myuser.role = role
                    myuser.save()
                    messages.success(request, 'Your account has been successfully created.')
            else:
                myuser = CustomUser.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                myuser.role = role
                myuser.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Your account has been successfully created.')
        else:   
            return HttpResponse('error occured')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    
    return render(request, 'signup/index.html', {'form': form, 'messages': messages.get_messages(request)})







def signin(request):
    pass



def logout(request):
    pass
```

signup.js

```
let container = document.getElementById('container')

toggle = () => {
    container.classList.toggle('sign-in')
    container.classList.toggle('sign-up')
}

setTimeout(() => {
    container.classList.add('sign-in')
}, 200)



gsap.from('ul.messages', {
    y: -200,
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 1
})

gsap.to('ul.messages', {
    y: -200,
    duration: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    delay: 3
})
```

These are the files that i am using for my signup page, I was expecting that the message block will be visible at the top but for some reason it isn't visible. The response that i was getting back showed that the message block is being added to the html document. I will really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you enable the messages middleware? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: yeah i did all my setting are correct